# Updating Artifactory pro from 6.10.9 to 7.6.3

Tags: artifactory

We just update our artifactory 6.10.9 to 7.6.3 on Ubuntu using debian package.
The migration.log show that the migration complete successfully
the service start bu we get a 404 when accessing the server.
There is errors on router-service.log:

```
 [jfrou] [FATAL] [1ef8ac7a8bab9898] [bootstrap.go:93] [main] - Cluster join: Failed resolving join key: failed resolving 'shared.security.joinKey' key; file does not exist: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key
```

in frontend-service.log :

```
[jffe ] [ERROR] [    ] [    ] [main] - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
```

in metadata-service.log :

```
[jffe ] [ERROR] [    ] [    ] [main] - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
```

And this is the first errors in the console.log :

```
2020-08-18T19:27:12.494Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [d2fc2e16d5fc1039] [actoryContextConfigListener:83] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Failed initializing Artifactory context: Artifactory home not initialized.
2020-08-18T15:27:12.495L [tomct] [SEVERE] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal] - One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2020-08-18T15:27:12.497L [tomct] [SEVERE] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal] - Context [/artifactory] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Does someone already had this kind of issue ? Thanks for clues.

Comment: Have you looked at https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-troubleshooting-artifactory-7-x-upgrade-issues/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error log snippet, it looks like the issue is with the router not coming up. Can you check the $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/log/router-service.log file if there is an error entry causing this issue?

Comment: In router-service.log, server try to find key file
[jfrou] [INFO ] [bootstrap.go:71      ] - Router (jfrou) service initialization started. Version: 1.4.0 PID: 10730 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
[jfrou] [INFO ] [security_keys.go:128 ] - Cluster join: Join key is missing. Pending for 115 seconds with 2m0s timeout
[jfrou] [FATAL] [bootstrap.go:93      ] - Cluster join: Failed resolving join key: failed resolving 'shared.security.joinKey' key; file does not exist: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key

Comment: as the join.key is missing under /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/ folder, it looks like Artifactory is not able to generate the join.key, can you refer to this wiki https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Keys#ManagingKeys-CreatingYourKeys and generate the join.key and place it under the /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key and try to restart the Artifactory.

Comment: manually creating /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key bring this error:
[jfrou] [FATAL] [bootstrap.go:101] [main] - could not join access, err: Cluster join: Service registry ping failed; context deadline exceeded. last error: Could not parse error from service registry, status code: 404
[jffe ] [ERROR] [main ] - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046
netstat -lntu
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8091 :::* LISTEN
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8040 :::* LISTEN
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8015 :::* LISTEN
tcp6 0 0 :::8081 :::* LISTEN
tcp6 0 0 :::22  :::*  LISTEN

Comment: There seems some issue connecting to Access I think. Can you check the access-service.log file for any suspicious entries?

Comment: Interesting things. looking at Dror Bereznitsky link, i realize that no valid JDBC drivers where on the installation.  Getting a JDBC driver supporting Java 11 in $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib bring only one error and many warnings
[jfac ] [ERROR] Could not validate router Check-url: http://10.X.X.X:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping
and lot of warnings 
[jfac ] [WARN ] Retry 440 Elapsed 3.66 minutes failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again

Comment: seems an issue again with the router, this URL "http://10.x.x.x:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping" is not valid as per router is trying to hit. Can you perform telnet over the IP 10.x.x.x on port 8082. Looks like 8082 on internal port is blocked. If it is a single Artifactory instance, change the IP in the system.yaml from 10.x.x.x to localhost and try to restart?

Comment: Thanks  Muhammed Kashif for your help

Answer (score 1):

Final problem was due to bad host file.  fixing it with good entries solved the last problem